# Where can I find extract recipes?

Tags: recipe

I'd like a few more options than the kits found at the local brew shop. Where do I look to find extract recipes that I won't need to convert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book "Brewing Classic Styles" covers pretty much the entirety of the BJCP styles with a recipe in every category. Nearly every single recipe is stated first as an extract plus specialty grain recipe first and mini mash and all grain as secondary versions. A couple of them can't really be done as extract versions and those are excluded.

It's 80 recipes, that have all won national awards and nearly all of them are based on extract.

[http://www.amazon.com/Brewing-Classic-Styles-Winning-Recipes/dp/0937381926](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0937381926)

Comment: I just bought this book and I love it.  I've been planning on investing in my home-brewery this year and budget constraints are forcing me to choose between kegging equipment and all-grain equipment.  The quality and variety of extract recipes in this book has encouraged me to go the kegging route.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with non-local homebrew shops.  [Austin Homebrew](http://www.austinhomebrew.com/index.php?cPath=178_452) has maybe a few hundred kit options.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [homebrew talk.](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f82/) Not only will you find recipes, but also ratings, and reviews from other users that have made them.